# Getting "This site can’t be reached" from remote server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a .NET MVC project and I'm trying to download a file from temporary folder. Here is my view code:

```
window.open('@Url.Action("DownloadDocument", "Controller")?fileName=' + fileName, '_blank');
```

And here is my controller code:

```
    public FileResult DownloadDocument(string fileName)
    {
        string path = Web.Common.Properties.Settings.Default.TempDocPath + "OpenTable\\";
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        return File(fileName, "application/xml", fileName + ".xml");
    }
```

This code works on IIS and file is being downloaded. But I'm getting 500 error when trying to download it from remote server.

> **This site can’t be reached**
>   The webpage at <...> might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

And the worst part is that there are some almost exact code snippets in the system which are working in both IIS and remote server.

Any suggestions what could be done?

**UPDATE**

Good news. When I tried postman it threw a file not found error with wrong path. It's an easy fix:

```
return File(Path.Combine(path, fileName), "application/xml", fileName + ".xml");
```

So it puzzles me... How and why it was working locally on IIS with wrong path?

Comment: Can you tell me what this 'Web.Common.Properties.Settings.Default.TempDocPath' return?

Comment: What happens when you ping the URL of the remote server? Can you access the remote server from your machine using Postman or via a browser?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your temp folder inside the root folder of your web app, for example ~/Temp, then use below code to access to that folder instead of Web.Common.Properties.Settings.Default.TempDocPath, I think this maybe just a constant.

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Temp")
```